# Why is the question "How do I find out salary for each HK Police Force rank?" off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

Apologies - Why [How do I find out salary for each HK Police Force rank?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/47565/27464) off topic?

> "This question does not appear to be about governments, policies and political processes within the scope defined in the help center." – JonathanReez Supports Monica, Alexei, JJ for Transparency and Monica, bytebuster, Erwan

[Who are the police in Hong Kong?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/42600/27464) is on topic. We also have [police](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/police) tag.

CCP and HK "governments" pay HKPF. Recent news validates that HKPF is executing their "policies".

Comment: I wouldn't say it's off-topic, but that question sounds like it might be too broad.  Questions of the form "list all the things of X" are generally at risk of being too broad.

Answer (score 9):

I think asking for a salary table of government employees is rather stretching [the scope of the site](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might argue it's a matter of government policy how much government employees are paid but I think it opens the door to a lot of uninteresting questions that are only tangentially related to politics.

While there is a [police](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/police) tag, it's mostly used, like other tags, to tag political questions related to the tag. In case of your question, I think it's reversed: you have a question about salary (not necessarily a political subject) and tie that to an existing tag.